# Me aparece este error cuando selecciono un pedido de libros, pero selecciono otro y no pasa nada

Tags: java

Me aparece este error en el servidor de Tomcat Apache y lo que no entiendo porque me aparece error eso si cuando selecciono otro pedido que no me sale, no tengo ni idea xD
`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP [detallespedido.jsp] en línea [67]

```
64:                             <h3 class="text-success">
65:                                 Detalles del Pedido NÂº 
66:                                 <% 
67:                                     String[] id = ModeloMVC.insertarDetallesPedido().get(1).split(" - ");
68:                                     out.println(id[0]);
69:                                 %>
70:                             </h3>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:626)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:515)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    es.studium.PracticaMVC.ServletControladorAplicacion.doPost(ServletControladorAplicacion.java:83)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
causa raíz

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.detallespedido_jsp._jspService(detallespedido_jsp.java:187)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    es.studium.PracticaMVC.ServletControladorAplicacion.doPost(ServletControladorAplicacion.java:83)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)`
```

Comment: El valor del index no está en la tabla a la que hace referencia

Comment: Pero es que no entiendo porque seleccionando otra cosa diferente no me pega fallos, va perfecto.

Comment: Es porque ese id si está en la tabla. Si haces un debug con un punto de interrupción puedes verificar el valor del index y con ese en la tabla.

Comment: En esta línea `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1` parece indica que se esta accediendo al indice 1 de un arreglo de tamaño 1 y cuando un arreglo tiene tamaño 1 el primer indice es 0